# I couldn't publish my app because of Permission policy

Tags: android, publishing, google-play-console

When I try to publish my app, I choose the reason of using "READ_SMS" permission - to auto-parsing SMS. But google reject app (from the Google Play Console) :

> Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Permissions policy. Before submitting your app for another review, read through the policy and make sure your app is in compliance.

I've removed this permission and auto-parsing of sms from my app, create new release build, but I still can't publish it ! In Console I still have this annoying message `"Your app is rejected because of Permission Policy"` and I couldn't do anything with it !

Someone can tell me how can I publish my app?

PS : I have also send an email to Google about using this permission in my app, but still no answer from them.

Comment: @KarthikKompelli - so I don't have answer from Google and simple create new Application in Play Market console with new apk, which doesn't use 'danger' permissions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google's policy and not a programming question